# Como criar classe corretamente com pandas, aplicando métodos?

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, classes, pandas

Tenho um arquivo 'dados.csv', com os dados abaixo:

```
turma,nome,code,motivo,atividade,trofeus,data
9º Ano Fundamental A,Maria Joana,9X4YK,Realizar atividade Astromaker,Lição A,3,21/02/2020 11:44:11
9º Ano Fundamental A,Maria Joana,9X4YK,Realizar atividade Astromaker,Lição B,3,28/02/2020 11:46:49
9º Ano Fundamental A,Maria Joana,9X4YK,Realizar atividade Astromaker,Lição B,3,06/03/2020 11:31:43
9º Ano Fundamental A,José Antonio,9XV62,Realizar atividade Astromaker,Lição B,3,14/02/2020 12:28:55
```

Criei uma classe para fazer a leitura do arquivo csv:

```
import pandas as pd


class DataFrame(object):
    def __init__(self, name_file):
        self.name_file = name_file
        self.df = self.read_file()
        return self.df

    def read_file(self):
        try:
            self.df = pd.read_csv(self.name_file)
        except IndexError:
            print('Erro: nome de arquivo incorreto')
        return self.df
```

A seguir eu inclui na mesma classe, funções para fazer filtros e agrupamentos, como por exemplo:

```
    def soma_trofeus_aluno(self):
        self.df = self.df.groupby(['turma', 'nome', 'code'])['trofeus'].sum().reset_index()

    def filtro_aluno(self, df, aluno):
        self.aluno = ''
        self.df = df[df['nome'].str.contains(self.aluno)]
        return self.df
```

Mas nenhuma das 'def' que tentei deu certo. Eu estou tentando chamar elas assim:

```
def main():
    dados = DataFrame('dados.csv')
    dados.filtro_aluno(dados, 'Maria')
    dados.exibir_df()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Como posso passar minhas 'def' corretamente e chamá-las?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro acontece porque o DataFrame da classe tem o nome de *df*, e na função *filtro_aluno* você definiu um dos parâmetros com o mesmo nome. Assim, se o operador *self* não for utilizado, uma confusão será gerada sobre a qual variável você está se referindo. Além do mais, a variável de parâmetro *df* dessa função é um objeto da classe DataFrame que você criou, e por isso obviamente não é possível iterá-la. Para resolver o problema, a linha

```
self.df = pd.DataFrame(self.df[self.df['nome'].str.contains(self.aluno)])
```

Deve ser substituída por

self.df = pd.DataFrame(self.df[self.df['nome'].str.contains(self.aluno)])

se você quiser manter o parâmetro *df* na função. Senão, apenas remova-o e você pode retirar os *self*'s que antecedem as referências ao atributo *df*.

O código completo fica assim (implementei por conta própria a função *exibir_df*, altere-a conforme suas necessidades):

```
import pandas as pd


class DataFrame(object):
    def __init__(self, name_file):
        self.name_file = name_file
        self.df = self.read_file()

    def read_file(self):
        try:
            self.df = pd.read_csv(self.name_file)
        except IndexError:
            print('Erro: nome de arquivo incorreto')
        return self.df
    
    def soma_trofeus_aluno(self):
        self.df = self.df.groupby(['turma', 'nome', 'code'])['trofeus'].sum().reset_index()

    def filtro_aluno(self, aluno):
        self.aluno = ''
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(self.df[self.df['nome'].str.contains(self.aluno)])
        return self.df
    
    def exibir_df(self):
        print (self.df)
    
def main():
    dados = DataFrame('dadoscsv')
    dados.filtro_aluno(dados, 'Maria')
    dados.exibir_df()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Boa, ajudou muito. Eu apenas apaguei o 'dados' em 'dados.filtro_aluno(dados, 'Maria')'. Muito show!!!

Answer (score 1):

`__init__` é o construtor e ele serve para inicializar a instância sendo criada. Você não deve retornar nada dele, não faz sentido. Ele só deveria fazer o necessário para criar uma instância válida (por exemplo, ler o arquivo e criar o *dataframe*):

```
def __init__(self, name_file):
    self.df = pd.read_csv(name_file)
```

Só isso (eliminei o método `read_file`, me pareceu redundante). Se der erro, ele lançará a exceção e a instância não será criada (afinal, faz sentido criar o `DataFrame` se o arquivo estiver inválido?) - leia mais a respeito [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/112052).

Não guardei o nome do arquivo em `self.name_file` porque você não usa ele para mais nada depois. Se o nome do arquivo não faz parte da classe (e só é usado para ler o arquivo), não guarde-o em um campo próprio. E me parece que não é necessário mesmo, pois o que interessa são os dados do arquivo (o `self.df`). Não guarde o que não será mais usado.

Uma vez criado o campo `self.df`, você pode usá-lo nos outros métodos. Mas há um detalhe, você está fazendo isso:

```
self.df = faz algo...
```

Ou seja, cada vez que você chama `soma_trofeus_aluno` ou `filtro_aluno`, esstará mudando o *dataframe* da classe. Faz sentido mudar os dados originais? Eu acho que não: suponha que você carregou todo o arquivo (ou seja, `self.df` contém todos os dados). Depois você chama `filtro_aluno` e filtra por "Maria". Ao fazer `self.df = resultado do filtro`, o campo `self.df` só terá os registros da Maria (os outros dados serão perdidos). Então neste caso faria sentido retornar o resultado em **outro** `DataFrame`, algo assim:

```
import pandas as pd

class DataFrame:
    # construtor recebe o nome do arquivo, ou o dataframe já criado
    def __init__(self, name_file = None, df = None):
        if name_file is not None:
            self.df = pd.read_csv(name_file)
        elif df is not None:
            self.df = df

    def soma_trofeus_aluno(self):
        # retorna outro DataFrame
        return DataFrame(df=self.df.groupby(['turma', 'nome', 'code'])['trofeus'].sum().reset_index())

    def filtro_aluno(self, aluno):
        # retorna outro DataFrame
        return DataFrame(df=self.df[self.df['nome'].str.contains(aluno)])

    def exibir_df(self):
        print(self.df)

def main():
    dados = DataFrame(name_file='dados.csv')
    # filtro é outro DataFrame só com os dados da Maria
    filtro = dados.filtro_aluno('Maria')
    filtro.exibir_df()
    # soma é outro DataFrame só com as somas dos alunos
    soma = dados.soma_trofeus_aluno()
    soma.exibir_df()
    # DataFrame original ainda tem todos os registros
    dados.exibir_df()
```

---

Dito tudo isso, será que precisava mesmo de uma classe para tudo isso? Por que não criar os dataframes separadamente, e ter funções para manipulá-los?

```
import pandas as pd

def read_df(name_file):
    return pd.read_csv(name_file)

def soma_trofeus_aluno(df):
    # retorna outro dataframe
    return df.groupby(['turma', 'nome', 'code'])['trofeus'].sum().reset_index()

def filtro_aluno(df, aluno):
    # retorna outro dataframe
    return df[df['nome'].str.contains(aluno)]

def main():
    dados = read_df(name_file='dados.csv')
    # filtro é outro dataframe só com os dados da Maria
    filtro = filtro_aluno(dados, 'Maria')
    print(filtro)
    # soma é outro dataframe só com as somas dos alunos
    soma = soma_trofeus_aluno(dados)
    print(soma)
    # dataframe original ainda tem todos os registros
    print(dados)
```

Comment: Meu caro, value demais, não sou dá area, mas estou estudando algumas linguagens de programação e marcação para usar na área de educação. Não sei pq isso não chega em nossa área, pois ajuda demais para melhor todo o dia a dia de um professor e uma escola. Acabei usando sua segunda opção, somente as `def` , pois aí deu certo jogar dentro de um "sisteminha" dentro do python mesmo podendo selecionar dados e filtros com as `def`. Assim, está resumindo em minutos trabalho de dias. SHOWWWW

Comment: @RonyDeiksonSantana Bom, eu diria para por enquanto não usar classes e focar só nos algoritmos e funções mesmo. Depois que dominar o básico, aí pode ir para coisas mais complicadas (classes/orientação a objetos é um tópico mais complicado e mesmo pessoas experientes na área batem cabeça com isso)

Comment: concordo. Vou focar nos algoritmos e `def`primeiro. O que já esta agilizando demais meu dia a dia com os alunos. Eu já consigo extrair do site um csv automático e postar resumo das lições tudo usando módulos python.

Comment: ainda bem que aqui no Stackoverflow consigo boas explicações e ajudas para evoluir.